# Charge accumulation on surface of solid sphere due to placement of dipole inside cavity

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, conductors, dipole

[image: pic 1]This is the case when a plus q charge is inside cavity (with same centre) of a spherical solid conductor. Everything is uniform. But what will it be like in second diagram [image: pic 2] I think the external electric field lines will be same as first diagram but the main question is about the third diagram,[image: pic 3]in this case there is a dipole inside cavity whose centre is not same as bigger solid sphere. So will there be any EF lines, will there be charge accumulation on surface of bigger sphere or it will get cancelled because of dipole despite of non uniform placement of charges inside cavity? What will the EF lines in third diagram be look like?[image: pic 4] my thoughts about third diagram are like this, since inside the cavity there is non-uniform charge distribution then, as shown in fourth diagram, there should be positive charge accumulation on right side as inside cavity there is negative charge on that side and same goes with left side. But I am not confirmed, Please guide me through this!!

Answer (score 0):

There would be no charge accumulation on the surface of bigger sphere, as the fields would canceled by charges on inner surface of cavity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).